# How to make triangle using series of numbers like this

Tags: c++

I have homework to make a triangle by using series of number like

[image: Sample Output]

But i dont know how to code it. I can make a simple triangle by using symbol just like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x, y;

    for (x=1; x<=3; x++) {
        for (y=x; y<3; y++) {
            cout << ".";
        }

        for (y=1; y<=x; y++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        for (y=1; y<=x-1; y++) {
            cout << "*";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need to make this using for() loop.
I can make that triangle but I can't make the calculation.
anyone can make a triangle code like the one in the picture?

Comment: Well yes I can code that, but doesn't seem like much point in me doing it if it's your homework. What part can't you do? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to compute subsequent rows after `8 9 10 9 8` row?  Is that what you are having trouble with

Comment: Create an array large enough to hold your longest row.  Compute these values using the values already in the array (from the previous row), and then output them.  Repeat for each row.

Comment: Output of numbers is easy even on console. But the little blue zig zag line would make me head-ache... ;-)

Comment: If rows `i` are numbered with index 0, 1, 2, ...; the start of row could be `4 * i`. Length of row is `2 * i + 1`, middle index `i + 1` respectively. What doesn't fit into this scheme is first row with `1`, but this might be tweaked with a `std::max(i, 1)`.

Comment: Unclear question. What exactly should the value be in the lines >3? (in other words, what should the program do, in English?)

Comment: @Ayjay i can do the triangle and i did make it the only problem i have is where the calculation should i put

Comment: @selbie noi just want to make the output just like the image

Comment: @paddy i tried but i failed to make the output like the the image

Comment: @user202729 i just want to make the output like the image, thats it

Comment: Why can't you just hard code the result? `std::cout << "   1\n  4 5 4\n8 9 10 9 8\n"`?

Comment: i can't sorry i forget to mention that i need to use for loop to make this.

Comment: @DevenValisten - Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  As you have it, you have a picture of a Pascal Triangle variant and said, "how can I make it look like the picture".  ou left out were important details such as 1) if this is a graphical program or console program. 2) If you are are just expected to print those three rows of numbers, or if you need to calculate additional rows. 3) The formula to compute a row. You can ask for help with your homework, but you need to state the problem clearly.

Comment: @selbie I apologize in advance because my question was not clear, 1. This is a console program, 2. I need to calculate it too 3. And I need to find the right formula too. So I have to make triangles like that by counting and making my own formulas.

Comment: Ok - I updated my answer to give you one additional hint.  You're on your own from here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint to get you started:

```
void printTriangle(int rows)
{
    vector<int> previousRow;
    vector<int> currentRow;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        if (r == 0)
        {
            currentRow = { 1 };
        }
        else if (r == 1)
        {
            currentRow = { 4,5,4 };
        }
        else
        {
            // todo: initialize currentRow based on the contents of previousRow
        }

        previousRow = currentRow;

        // todo: your code to print the numbers in currentRow
    }
}
```

Update:

Since you have since clarified your question above, here's another hint.

Pseudo-code for computing a subsequent row (referencing the previous row)

```
currentRow.size = previousRow.size + 2;
j = 0;
current = previous = previousRow[j];
for (i = 0; i < currentRow.size; i++)
    currentRow[i] = previous + current
    previous = current;
    current = previousRow[++j]
```